# "If anybody answer this question" or "If anybody answerS this question"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

What is correct - 
"If anybody answer this question please let me know" 
or 
"If anybody answers this question please let me know"

Thank you.

Comment: Which one would you choose and why?

Comment: Can you use "If anybody knows answer to this question , please let me know"?

Comment: If one believe there be a subjunctive mood in English, one may well ask whether this sentence should be subjunctive, and if not, why not? Perfectly natural question, and the answer is also. There is in fact no subjunctive mood in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Anybody* is singular and third person, right?  So *answers*.